# How do i get data from a page to other page,just simply display on screen with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

```css
<style>div.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 800px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Your Selection</h1>
  <p>Here is the information you have submitted:</p>
  <div class="container">
    <ol>
      <li><em>AID:</em>
        <?php echo $_POST['aid']?>
      </li>
      <li><em>Date of Arrival:</em>
        <?php echo $_POST['Arrival']?>
      </li>
      <li><em>Number of Days:</em>
        <?php echo $_POST['Days']?>
      </li>
      <li><em>Number of Adults:</em>
        <?php echo $_POST['adults']?>
      </li>
      <li><em>Number of Children</em>
        <?php echo $_POST['children']?>
      </li>
      <li><em>Total:</em>
        <?php echo $_POST['Total']?>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="container" align="left">
    <form action="" method="post">
      Name : <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" /><br> 
      Phone Number : <input type="number" name="number" placeholder="Phone Number" /><br> 
      Email : <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" /><br> 
      Address : <input type="text"
        name="Address" placeholder="Address" /><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Confirm">
      <input type="submit" value="Cancel">
    </form>
  </div>



</body>
```

As the code runs it will print out the information that user already select and type previously. Whenever the user clicks on submit, it will turn to receipt page and list the data on the screen.

Comment: What's problem you are facing?

Comment: how do i bring these data to a new page?

Comment: in the form, action gives the new-page URL and write your `<ol></ol>` code on that page. Tha's it.

Comment: but I also want those blank field detail shown as well

Comment: `blank field detail shown as well – `? what blank filed?

Comment: it will be in the container class, I want the name, address, number, etc... on the new page as well, should I use a get method?  LIke form method get something

Comment: so first show data on the same page and then redirect to a new page after some time?

Comment: so everything will show on new pages

Comment: What you want is confusing? When you fill the form and hit submit button what you need to happen? data will show on this page only or data need to be shown on the new page or data first show on the same page and then after some time, data will show on next page?

Comment: I want after user type data into the blank and click "submit", a new page will come out and shown what user typed previously.

Comment: sorry made it complexed to  understand

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: You don't have `Aid`,`Arrival`,`Days` in your form then how you will get that data?

Comment: ok, I have three pages. aid, arrival and days data will be collected from page 1 and displayed on page 2, and then user continuous type data on page 2 and click "submit", then  every data will show on page 3.

Comment: your first page data need to come in the second page in hidden fields and then on submitting all data will goes to 3 page.Mean first page data need to be add as hidden field data with corresponding name attribute in the second page inside <form></form>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example window.location() and send the data you want to display in the Query String. i.e:

```
window.location = "http://www.home.com/page/?info=whateverYouNeed";
```

And then you can get the query string with:

```
window.href.url
```

There are numerous ways of doing this including using ajax to post to the backend and then retrieve it using ajax get request from the data destination page.

I hope I understood your question right and that the answer was appropriate.

Comment: i think i should use a get method

Comment: $.ajax() for instance, but you need to Post it before from the other page in order to access it.